# Is it possible for an overlay command as the next statement after an if?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Is it possible to use an if before an overlay?

The example code shows a blue square with an overlay of text and a highlight just below the text. And if the number in the text matches the day number of the month, then the blue box shows a white border.

Getting the code to work is fairly easy if you only have one if statement, because you can place all objects inside the if. Although if there are multiple if scenarios (such as different border colours according to different situations) the most efficient way (from the perspective of making it readable) would be to insert the if between the Color object and the .overlay.

As a result of trying to make it more efficient I have tried a variety of methods (such as self.overlay etc).

This is the example and shortened code - I have inserted the if statement after the "//" in lines 7 to ten that I think would make it more efficient (to read) if I could get it to work (where I would put a series of ifs):

```
struct exampleCode: View {
        let textRef : Int
        var body : some View {
                Color(red:20/255,green: 45/255, blue:50/255)
                    .frame(width:50, height:56)
                    .cornerRadius(6)
                //if(Calendar.current.component(.day, from: Date()) == dayRef){
                //    self.overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                //        .stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 2))
                //}
                    .overlay(alignment:.center){
                VStack (spacing: -4){
                Spacer()
                Text(String(textRef))
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .font(Font.system(size: 26, weight: .bold))
                Spacer()
                    Color(red:20/255,green: 255/255, blue:71/255)
                        .frame(width:20, height:6)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, you want to display a different overlay based on some condition?

Comment: same overlay although a different potential borders to the square the overlay sits on

Comment: Thank you, i may need to read it a few times to understand but I appreciate your assistance

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not possible.

One solution is a conditional ViewModifier but this creates a new view and maybe will break animations.

There is an alternative: Apply the ternary operator and pass `nil` for *no change*.

```
struct ExampleCode: View { // please name struct uppercase
    let textRef : Int
    let isSameDay = Calendar.current.component(.day, from: Date()) == dayRef // where does dayRef come from?
    var body : some View {
            Color(red:20/255,green: 45/255, blue:50/255)
                .frame(width:50, height:56)
                .cornerRadius(6)
                .overlay(isSameDay 
                    ? RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                        .stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 2)
                    : nil)

                .overlay(alignment:.center){
            VStack (spacing: -4){
            Spacer()
            Text(String(textRef))
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .font(Font.system(size: 26, weight: .bold))
            Spacer()
                Color(red:20/255,green: 255/255, blue:71/255)
                    .frame(width:20, height:6)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Arguably, this is the simplest implementation. I'd also recommend creating a separate "Overlay View" that takes your reference data, for making conditional decisions, and having the initialization of the view, self configure before it's returned. Particularly if you're planning to have multiple conditions, else the ternary is going to get really messy.